# MS WORD 2016 for windows forms

Tags: ms-word

I am trying to develop a form in word 2016 for windows such that I have check boxes for multiple options.  I am trying to print the checkboxes that are selected as well as their respective descriptions only.  I found this code on line, but it doesn't seem to work for 2016:

```
With ActiveDocument 
  .Unprotect 
  If .FormFields("Check1").CheckBox.Value = False Then 
    .Bookmarks ("CheckBox1Text").Range.Font.Hidden=True 
  Else 
    .Bookmarks("CheckBox1Text").Range.Font.Hidden=False 
  End If 
  .Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset 
End With
```

Comment: Please explain how the code isnot working.